# Wifi not working on Raspberry Pi3 for Ubuntu server 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: drivers, server, broadcom

I have a Raspberry Pi3 with the Broadcom 43430 chipset. The WiFi stops to work with the bionic and focal server images with a message saying that it could not find the `clm_blob`.

The only remedy I have found to continue using my Raspberry has been to switch to Alpine Linux 3.15 and install their `firmware-cypress` APK to make the WiFi work again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Naugh... It may be as "complex" as installing an additional package(e.g. Alpine), but the whole procedure there is too lengthy to make sense to newbies using a Rasperry Pi! Remember: user-friendliness also counts!